# How to keep empty fields from appearing in php?

Tags: php

Please help... I have managed to do some basic PHP coding to call author meta and url information on single post, but I do not know how to hide the empty data fields.

Can anybody give me any pointers? Many thanks

```
<div id="about-author" class="clearfix"><h3 class="block-title">About <a href="<?php  echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>?rel=author"><font color="#d1004b"><?php the_author(); ?></a></font></h3>
<div class="twocol first"><center><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>"><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 90 ); ?></a><br>Get Social<br>
<a href="<?php the_author_url(); ?>" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-globe" title="Website"></i></a>
<a href="//www.twitter.com/<?php the_author_meta('twitter'); ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" title="Twitter"></i></a>
<a href="<?php the_author_meta('googleplus'); ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square" title="Google+"></i></a>
<a href="<?php the_author_meta('linkedin'); ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" title="LinkedIn"></i></a></center></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide, for example,  `the_author_meta('linkedin');` if no data exists for that field, then you could just do the following

```
<?php if(!empty(get_the_author_meta('linkedin'))) { ?> 
        <a href="<?php the_author_meta('linkedin'); ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" title="LinkedIn"></i></a> 
<?php } ?>`
```

and then apply similar logic to other fields. If this is not what you were asking, then you should explain a little more about what you are trying to accomplish.